# Firebase hosting with only ONE A record

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I have my client's domain registered via 1and1.com

To connect the domain to the Firebase hosting, Firebase asks me to add *TWO* A records with 2 IPs. In 1and1 we can only add *ONE* A record. Yesterday Firebase sent me this message by mail

> Please re-verify ownership of www.*******.com on
>   *******-website. The previous verification for this domain has
>   been invalidated. You have 1 day to re-verify ownership of
>   www.*******.com before it is removed from Firebase Hosting,
>   which will stop all content from being served from the domain. Please
>   visit the Firebase Hosting Panel to start the re-verification process.

Today the website was disconnected.

I reconnected the domain to the Firebase hosting through the Firebase control panel and got the website up again. But the Firebase control panel says it still needs setup

I am sure it will disconnect it again soon. How to solve that? (I already called 1and1 and they told me no way I would be able to add another A record.) 
[image]

Comment: My first solution will be adding 2 `A` records as they asked. Is changing registrar an option?

Comment: Impossible unfortunately

Comment: the client wouldn't let me change the registrar as he has everything setup for his other domains, email, other projects at 1and1

Comment: It starts to sound like a non-technical problem to me :o

Comment: There should be a _technical_ workaround :)

Comment: or maybe a Firebase config

Comment: I'm not as optimistic but good luck :)

Comment: It is 21st century, and you can't have 2 `A` records? (I find it hard to believe, my guess is that either you got someone clueless from their tech support, or they misunderstood what you need). Workaround: create CNAME pointing to hostname.at.someother.decent.registrar, and create A record with 2 ip addresses there.

Comment: Same problem with STRATO Webhosting. Support confirmed that it is only possible to add one A-Record per domain.

Comment: Ok, now we have a list of domain providers we should not use in 2017 :) Anyways, the website is still up since then and Firebase never took it down.

Comment: Same problem here, stay away from 1und1. I will change registrar's ASAP, they have been consistently terrible for over a year. It's worth paying a few extra dollars to make sure things work...

Answer (score 2):

I set up in the same way a website (https://lasi17.snola.es/) and it seems to work with only one A record pointing out to the Firebase IP.

In my case, I just changed the option in Hosting -> Domains -> Your custom domain (in my case lasi17.snola.es) -> Process traffic in this domain (*"Edit" under the kebab menu*). After that, the domain works as usual with only one A record configured.

Comment: It does work and it's working now. But as I said in the question, Firebase took down the website when I couldn't add the second IP. Now it's up again. Hope Firebase won't take it down again

Comment: In my case, Firebase didn't take the website down in any moment. I only displays to me the error in the console set up

Comment: still no downtime @juancb ?

Comment: Same problem with me, I called them and they told me it was possible to add only one record. After 1 hour, my website was working but I still have the error in my firebase account (telling me to configure the 2nd record).
Does anyone know what are the risks to have only one record ? (except having his website potentially down due to a lack of configuration in firebase)

Comment: I did not need to Edit -> Process traffic from this domain for single IP as it is not for this purpose. 

As said earlier single IP may work but it *can* have down time. Also firebase will keep displaying incomplete setup notice for 2nd IP.