# How to host on firebase with one A record with 1and1?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to host my website on firebase through a domain I purchase through 1and1. 1and1 only gives me an option to have one A record though I need two to verify through firebase.

It is the same issue as [Firebase hosting with only ONE A record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43106745/firebase-hosting-with-only-one-a-record) , but I am not able to use this solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately both A records are needed to verify with Firebase Hosting. One possibility, if it's not an apex domain (e.g. this will work for `www.mydomain.com` but not `mydomain.com`), is to use a `CNAME` pointed to `<yourapp>.firebaseapp.com`.

If it's an apex domain, you'll need to switch to a DNS provider that supports multiple A records.